# Maximum Inflight messages in mosquitto

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

How to increase the inflight message count in mosquitto broker so that client can publish `n` number of messages to be saved in the broker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the *max_inflight_messages* in the mosquitto.conf file.

http://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html

Comment: sorry i am new to mqtt. but is not that similar "retain" the messages on the broker?

Comment: retained is different. Retained just means the last retained message on a topic will be delivered at the point of subscription no matter what else may be queued for delivery (due to previous subscription and disconnect or QOS level). See the Retained section of the Mosquitto man page for details: http://mosquitto.org/man/mqtt-7.html