# Is it possible to set the in-flight limit for AWS IoTCore MQTT connections?

Tags: python, mqtt, aws-iot-core

I'd like to ensure that my packets are received in-order by IoTCore. As QoS2 is not available it looks like the only way to do that in-client is to limit the number of in flight messages to 1. This is described well in answers to other questions for different clients:

- [Is message order preserved in MQTT messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30955110/is-message-order-preserved-in-mqtt-messages)
- [Maximum Inflight messages in mosquitto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26314582/maximum-inflight-messages-in-mosquitto)

However, although I can see how to set this in Paho I cannot see how to set it using the awssdk2 for Python.

- https://awslabs.github.io/aws-crt-python/api/mqtt.html#awscrt.mqtt.Connection
- https://pypi.org/project/awsiotsdk/

So my questions are:

1. What is the in-flight limit set for AWS IoTCore MQTT?
2. Is it possible to change that limit?

All suggestions appreciated.

Ed

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The [developer guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/mqtt.html) states "The message broker doesn't guarantee the order in which messages and ACK are received". So even if you wait on the QOS1 ACK before sending another message there is still no guarantee that  messages will reach subscribers in order. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46558714/11810946) for more info.

Comment: I think that is the reason to limit in-flight messages to 1 as set out in my question.